# Sequelize Add Column and Foreign Key Constaint in same migration file

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is my current migration

up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

```
return Promise.all([
    queryInterface.addColumn(
    'carts',
    'user_id',
    {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
    ).then(() => {
        queryInterface.addConstraint('carts', {
        fields: ['user_id'],
        type: 'foreign key',
        name: 'cart_user_id_fkey',
        references: {
            table: 'users',
            field: 'user_id'
        }   
    })
    })
])
/**
 * Add altering commands here.
 *
 * Example:
 * await queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
 */
```

},

I first add the column, then the constraint to the table. When I run this I get this error:

(node:7106) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bazaah`.`#sql-5c24_1325d`, CONSTRAINT `cart_user_id_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`))

Why does trying to add a constaint fail after adding the column?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a not-null field w/o any default value. You either indicate a default value or make it nullable until you fill this field in all records.

```js
{
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true
    }
```

In your case, I don't see what value should be used as the default one so the only option you have is to make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      UserId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Users",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      HeroId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "Heros",
          key: "id"
        }
      },
      match: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      status: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).